# Framework argparse - check if flag is set

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I want to use my script in this way: python script.py -x
now I run it using this command python script.py -x y

My code:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x', '--x', dest="x", default="n")
options = parser.parse_args()
if option.x == 'y':
    f()
```

It is possible to write it in this way

**python script.py -x**

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x', '--x', dest="x")
options = parser.parse_args()
if isset(option.x):
    f()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the [`'store_true'` action](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x', action='store_true')
```

then you can simply test for the truthiness of that argument:

```
options = parser.parse_args()
if options.x:
    f()
```

In use, just printing whether or not that argument is truth-y:

```
C:\Python27>python so.py
x is not set

C:\Python27>python so.py -x
x is set
```

Comment: Is that a typo? options = parser.parse_args() but you check option.x...

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino what makes you think that's a typo; what would you have expected? Did this not work for you?

Comment: in `option.x` place shouldn't it be `options.x` because you said it in the previous line? `options = parser.parse_args()`

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino ah I see; yes, that's a typo, thanks!