# Python argparse how to pass False from the command line?

Tags: python

I am trying to sort out how to pass the boolean value False from the command line to the argparser. My origninal code looked like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=True)
parser.add_argument('-data', default=True, type=bool, help='uses the history file')
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

From the command line, I typed: python myscript.py -data False

Also variations with single & double quotes around False. When I examine the contents of the args namespace, args.data is always True.

So I changed the argument definition from bool to str, with a string "True" default as shown below:

```
parser.add_argument('-data', default="True", type=str, help='uses the history file')
```

I then added some massaging of the args to get the boolean value I really wanted:

```
if re.search("f", args.data, re.I):
   args.data = False
else:
   args.data = True
```

This workaround does work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `bool` converts any non-empty string to True https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python

Comment: You can also use `store_true` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884131/framework-argparse-check-if-flag-is-set

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `store_false` or `store_true` parameter to `add_argument` (see [the argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action)). For example, if you want the default to be `True` then you could add an argument with `action='store_false'`:

```
parser.add_argument('--no-data', action='store_false', help="don't use the history file")
```

Then `args.no_data` will be `False` if you run `python command.py --no-data` and `True` if you run `python command.py` without the `--no-data` argument.

Comment: Thanks very much! action='store_false' is what I needed.

Comment: Wouldn't using some other variable name make more sense? Something like `dest='data'` That way, it's not `args.no_data` which is false, but `args.data`

Answer (score 5):

```
def my_bool(s):
    return s != 'False'

parser.add_argument('-data',default=True,type=my_bool)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I cannot use flags in my application, for now.

Answer (score 5):

If an argument is meant to be a boolean, you should simply use `store_true` or `store_false`, so that the presence of the option itself would result in a `True` or `False` value, and the absence of the option would result in a `False` or `True` value, respectively.

From [argparse's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
>>> parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo --bar'.split())
Namespace(foo=True, bar=False, baz=True)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! action='store_false' is what I needed.

Comment: Can I use both `store_true` and `store_false`?

Comment: What do you mean to achieve with both options enabled? The value of an option can't be both `True` and `False`.